# One Upstart to rule them all

Tags: daemon, upstart

I have a single project `foo` consisting of several daemons e.g. `foo-web`, `foo-worker` and `for-cleanup`. For each of them I have a very simple Upstart script, allowing me to use commands like `service foo-web start`.

What I really want is to have another Upstart script to control the whole application at once. So I can use `service foo restart` to relaunch the whole thing and have `start on`, `stop on` and `respawn` stanzas written only once for the entire project.

How can I achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use upstart/system V scripts to manage single daemon.

For more complex operations like the one above(group few services together and start them as one service), I use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). Upstart scripts are too low level.

Monit has more features and benefits.

Comment: Looking promising. Could you please provide a control file example that solves my particular problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/deep-thought-42/9020178#file-monit_group_example is an example monit conf file. With this setup, you can do "monit -g foo start", "monit -g foo stop", "monit -g foo restart"